# Playing Video doesn't work

Tags: android, video, android-video-player

I wont to play a video in my application ...
I write the code as below:

```
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public TextView counter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcomepage);
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView); 
    Log.e("ok","ok");
    videoView.setVideoPath("animationgif/vid.flv");
    videoView.start();  }
}
```

but it doesn't work !!! have anyone any solution plz !

Comment: Please provide a bit more about "doesn't work" and what you've tried to fix it.

Comment: Error: animationgif/vid.flv doesnot existe !!!

Comment: You're not pointing to a real path. Also Android doesn't support FLV. See this link for supported media formats http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a video from external storage (sdcard or phone):

```
videoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/file.mp4");
```

To do it from the raw folder:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.video));
```

Android doesn't support flv. It supports mp4 and 3gp (mkv starting with Android 4.0). See this link for supported media formats http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html.